# Guided mode does not show a preview

Tags: bug, ask-question-wizard-2018

I can't see a preview of the question while making it, it is not updated as you type in the form. The preview in traditional mode works.

A workaround i found consists in write anything in the final step (the review your question one).

- Web browser: Google Chrome
- Version: 73.0.3683.75 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
- OS: GNU/Linux

Comment: I removed the status-review tag since this pertains to the old ask wizard and is no longer relevant.